# How to remove a part of a image using another image

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I've got two images, one of them I'll create using `Graphics` (a simple circle/ellipse).

Now I want to remove a part of the circle using another image. It should support removing alpha values too.

[image]

> I hope the link works, if not please write it into comments & I'll fix it.

Thanks for any advice

**EDIT:**

Image 2 does not really have any border, it is just to show the frame size...

Comment: @Aybe, thanks for embing the image, I hadn't got enough reputation. :D

Comment: are you using Forms or WPF ?

Comment: no, I'm using winforms but your code helped me to fix my problem. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I wrote the code by myself. This is it:

```
public static Bitmap RemovePart(Bitmap source, Bitmap toRemove)
{
    Color c1, c2, c3;
    c3 = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
    {
       for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
       {
           c1 = source.GetPixel(x, y);
           c2 = toRemove.GetPixel(x, y);
           if (c2 != c3)
           {
               source.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(c2.A, c1));
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var image1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("1.png", UriKind.Relative));
            var image2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("2.png", UriKind.Relative));
            var bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.ConvertToPbgra32Format(image1);
            var bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.ConvertToPbgra32Format(image2);

            var width = 256;
            var height = 256;
            var bitmap3 = BitmapFactory.New(width, height);

            var transparent = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    var color1 = bitmap1.GetPixel(x, y);
                    var color2 = bitmap2.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color color3;
                    if (color1.Equals(transparent))
                    {
                        color3 = transparent;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (color2.Equals(transparent))
                        {
                            color3 = color1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            color3 = transparent;
                        }
                    }
                    bitmap3.SetPixel(x, y, color3);
                }
            }
            Image1.Source = bitmap3;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've used https://www.nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx/ to make things simpler, be careful about having 32-bit PNG as well as what is a transparent color because in WPF it is a transparent white in fact.

You should be able to translate that to Forms easily if this is what you're using, with this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

EDIT : you could have used an opacity mask but since pic.2 does not its outer dark, it wouldn't have worked.